# how can I stream rows, in a loop, from Postgres? (F#/.NET but any other language is fine)

Tags: postgresql

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
(
    instrument     varchar(20)                 NOT NULL,
    ts             timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    price          float8                      NOT NULL,
    quantity       float8                      NOT NULL,
    direction      int                         NOT NULL
);
```

and I'd like to keep in my app the last hour of data; so upon startup, query everything where *ts >= now - 1h*, and then keep a loop where I query from the last row received to 'now'.

We're talking about roughly 1.5M rows to fetch at startup.

The issue is that the timestamp is not unique: you can have multiple rows with the same timestamp.

I am requesting an update every second with a limit of 50k, and it usually produces 200-500 rows; but the startup is providing batches of 50k rows until it catches up with the new data.

Should I:

- add an id, find the id of now - 1h, and request records with an id higher than the last one received?
- roll back the last timestamp received by 1s and deal with duplicates
- something better I didn't think about (I'm not very knowledgeable with SQL DBs)

Comment: Looking at a primary key ID will be much faster than comparing timestamps, since it will be indexed, so that's not a bad thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea.

If there is a single writer (which is to say, a single client `INSERT`ing to this table), you can use an autoincrementing ID to avoid having do deal with duplicates. Add an ID column, query for the last hour, keep your largest-seen ID in memory, and then run your loop of `id>largest_seen_id` every second. This is pretty standard, but does rely on IDs always becoming visible to the querier in increasing order, which isn't something the DB can guarantee in the general case.

If there are multiple writers, it's possible for this approach to skip rows, as a higher ID might be committed while another client still has it's lower-id row in an open transaction, and not visible to your query. Your next iteration would have the higher id as the lower bound, so you never end up seeing the committed lower-ID row. The easiest way of dealing with that is what you're already thinking of with your second option: query for extra rows and ignore the ones you already have. If network transfer is an issue, you can do the ignoring in the WHERE of the loop query you're running, so you're only "wasting" the size of the already-seen row IDs, instead of all the row data:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_appending_table
WHERE timestamp > ('2021-08-24 00:10:07' - interval '5 seconds')
  AND NOT id=ANY({99101,99105,99106})
ORDER BY id asc
LIMIT 50000
```

Where `2021-08-24 00:10:07` is the max timestamp you currently have (probably fine to use the timestamp of the max-ID row; not guaranteed to be the same but basically always will be), 5 seconds is a fuzz to ensure all other writers have committed, and 99101,99105,99106 are the IDs you've already seen for rows with timestamp 2021-08-24 00:10:**02** (:07 - 5) or later.